# Plotting several X,Y column pairs as data series, while excluding (0,0) points

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to plot three data series in a single plot. The X and Y coordinates of each series are in separate columns in my data frame:

```
    X1  Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3
1   0   1   0   2   0   3
2   1   2   1   3   1   4
3   2   3   2   4   2   5
4   3   4   3   5   3   6
5   4   5   4   6   4   7
6   5   6   5   7   5   8
7   6   7   6   8   6   9
8   0   0   7   9   7   8
9   0   0   8   8   0   0
10  0   0   9   7   0   0
```

Since the trailing (0,0) data points of each series are invalid, only this subset of points should eventually be plotted:

```
    X1  Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3
1   0   1   0   2   0   3
2   1   2   1   3   1   4
3   2   3   2   4   2   5
4   3   4   3   5   3   6
5   4   5   4   6   4   7
6   5   6   5   7   5   8
7   6   7   6   8   6   9
8           7   9   7   8
9           8   8       
10          9   7
```

Additionally, the X-axis of the first series should be inverted:

[image: Correct plot]

Even without cleaning up with data frame first, I struggled to plot the column pairs as individual series in ggplot2 (see 'legend').

```
require(ggplot2)

report <- function(df){
  plot = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=-X1, y=Y1, size=3)) + #inverted X-axis of series 1
    layer(geom="point") +
    geom_point(aes(X2, Y2, colour="red", size=2)) + 
    geom_point(aes(X3, Y3, colour="blue", size=1)) +
    xlab("X") + ylab("Y")
  print(plot)
}

X1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0)
Y1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,0)

X2 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
Y2 = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7)

X3 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0)
Y3 = c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,0,0)

df <- data.frame(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3)
colnames(df) <- c("X1","Y1","X2","Y2","X3","Y3")

report(df)
```

[image: Incorrect plot]

What would be the best way to get rid of the invalid (0,0) data points in each series, and how should I plot them properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you actually want to transform your `data.frame` in order to make your `ggplot` call more concise. Here is the updated version to plot your data correctly using the `dplyr` package to transform the data.

In response to comment requesting additional info on `dplyr`. It provides the `%>%` operator which simply passed the argument to the left into the function on the right as the first argument. It allows for much more readable `R` code. The `mutate` function adds the `Series` variable via a manual setting of the variable given the knowledge of which points are part of which series. Then the `filter` function removes the `0,0` points which you indicated were not wanted. You can inspect the `df` after these operations to see the final output. Hope this helps interpret the below code. Also here is a [link to the `dplyr` page](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

```
library(dplyr)
df <- rbind.data.frame(
    data.frame(X=-X1, Y=Y1),
    data.frame(X=X2, Y=Y2),
    data.frame(X=X3, Y=Y3))
df <- df %>%
    mutate(Series=rep(c('S1', 'S2', 'S3'), each=10)) %>%
    filter(!(X == 0 & Y == 0))
png('foo.png')
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=X, y=Y, color=Series, size=Series))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Also if you want to manual set the values of color and size as well as adding the lines as in your ideal example plot, here is a more complex `ggplot` command:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, color=Series, size=Series)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line(size=1) + theme_bw() +
    scale_color_manual(values=c('black', 'red', 'blue')) +
    scale_size_manual(values=seq(4,2,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace `rbind.data.frame` with just `rbind`.

Comment: Are you missing something in your comment @NickK? Not sure if you meant the `dplyr` function `bind_rows`, but I certainly could have done that, I just choose not to.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, this seems to work great. Would you care to explain how the mutate function works here in a bit more detail? 

`df <- df %>%
    mutate(Series=rep(c('S1', 'S2', 'S3'), each=10)) %>%`